# Classnames 'Void' inside vendor/magento/

Tags: magento2, php-7, setup-di-compile

I'm trying to re-compile using

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

But when I run this command, I get:

> Fatal error:  Cannot use 'Void' as class name as it is reserved in  /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Void.php on line 9

I am running PHP 7.1.0-alpha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Magento 2 is yet compatible with php 7.1-alpha, but this is an alarm signal.
I think you should report this on [github](http://github.com/magento/magento2).
It could be an issue in the near future,

Comment: Github issue for reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7663

Answer (score 20):

Here is how to fix it:

1. edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/webapi.xml` line 112:

   ```
   - <route url="/V1/invoices/:id/void" method="POST">
   + <route url="/V1/invoices/:id/voidInvoice" method="POST">
   ```
2. edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/View.php` line 242:

   ```
   - return $this->getUrl('sales/*/void', ['invoice_id' => $this->getInvoice()->getId()]);
   + return $this->getUrl('sales/*/voidInvoice', ['invoice_id' => $this->getInvoice()->getId()]);
   ```
3. edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/View.php` line 183:

   ```
   - return $this->getUrl('sales/*/void', ['creditmemo_id' => $this->getCreditmemo()->getId()]);
   + return $this->getUrl('sales/*/voidCreditmemo', ['creditmemo_id' => $this->getCreditmemo()->getId()]);
   ```
4. edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Void.php` line 9:

   ```
   - class Void extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\View
   + class VoidInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\View
   ```
5. edit `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/Void.php` line 10:

   ```
   - class Void extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
   + class VoidCreditmemo extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
   ```
6. rename

   `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/Void.php`

   to

   `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/VoidCreditmemo.php`
7. rename

   `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Void.php`

   to

   `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/VoidInvoice.php`

taken from https://mage2.pro/t/topic/2433/2

Comment: you are very welcome sir

Comment: in Magento Enterprise mv vendor/magento/module-reward/Model/Action/Creditmemo/Void.php vendor/magento/module-reward/Model/Action/Creditmemo/VoidCreditmemo.php
in line 8 change class Void to class VoidCreditmemo

Comment: @KonstantinGerasimov, 
Is there any patch available for M230 ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the core magento vendor files to resolve the issue it would make more sense to use the right php version. Depending on what you are using, it should be easy enough to set a BASH configuration for a particular php bin location.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer an issue for Magento 2.2 - Magento 2.1 was not PHP7.1 compatible.